# Creating dynamic xml feed automatically encode some tags

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I'm creating dynamically xml file using code below

```
var xrFeed = new XmlTextWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.UTF8);
xrFeed.WriteStartDocument();
xrFeed.WriteStartElement("ads");


foreach (var i in items)
{
    xrFeed.WriteStartElement("ad");
    xrFeed.WriteElementString("id", "<![CDATA[" + i.AdId+ "]]>");                
    xrFeed.WriteEndElement();
}

xrFeed.WriteEndElement();
xrFeed.WriteEndDocument();

xrFeed.Flush();
xrFeed.Close();
Response.End();
DataBind();
```

as output I get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads>
  <ad>
     <id>&lt;![CDATA[12345]]&gt;</id>
  </ad>
</ads>
```

but I need not to encode < tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ads>
  <ad>
     <id><![CDATA[12345]]></id>
  </ad>
</ads>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
xrFeed.WriteElementString("id", "<![CDATA[" + i.AdId+ "]]>");
```

Do:

```
xrFeed.WriteStartElement("id");
xrFeed.WriteCData(i.AdId);
xrFeed.WriteEndElement();
```

The `XmlTextWriter` will encode any special characters, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
< ![CDATA[" + i.AdId+ "]] >
```

to

```
& lt;![CDATA[12345]]& gt;
```

just delete the spacing... between & lt or & gt;

Comment: That would output `&amp; lt;![CDATA[12345]]&amp; gt;`